# What does this symbol $\otimes$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I came across the symbol $\otimes$ as below and I would like to know what this symbol $\otimes$ means:

> $\text{.... the projection operator P is given by: }$
>   $$P = I_nd - \nabla G^T(\nabla G \nabla G^T)^{-1} \nabla G= I_{nd} - I_d \otimes uu^T,$$ where $I_x$ denotes the identity matrix of size $x\times x$ and $\mathbf{u}$ is the unit vector , $\mathbf{u} = (1,1,1,\dots,1)/\sqrt{n})$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Tensor product, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: Also see: [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), which is the same thing in matrix notation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this context, $\otimes$ refers specifically to the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  In particular, we have
$$
I_d \otimes B 
= \overbrace{B \oplus B \oplus \dots \oplus B}^d
= \text{diag}(\overbrace{B,B, \dots, B}^d)\\
= \pmatrix{B\\&B\\&&\ddots\\&&&B}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Here is an official reference, more or less, from Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* (3rd. ed., p. 421):

> Let $A=(\alpha_{ij})$ and $B$ be $r\times n$ and $s\times m$ matrices, respectively, with coefficients from any commutative ring. The *Kronecker product* or *tensor product* of $A$ and $B$, denoted by $A\otimes B$, is the $rs\times nm$ matrix consisting of an $r\times n$ block matrix whose $i, j$ block is the $s\times m$ matrix $\alpha_{ij} B$.

Answer (score 0):

It means the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)...

Answer (score 0):

Tensor Product.
Check here for reference. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

EDIT: Ninja'd