# The notation $ \otimes $ (Tensor product)

Tags: notation

Related to the question [Riemannian manifolds isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558608/riemannian-manifolds-isometry), could anyone be able to explain to me what the notation $ \otimes $? Some examples were given in the question : $dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy = \frac12(dz\otimes d\bar z + d\bar z\otimes dz) = |dz|^2$ or $dw \otimes d\bar{w}$.

**Clarification :** I think my question is different of [What does this symbol $\otimes$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271853/what-does-this-symbol-otimes-mean), because I would like some details on a specific example.

Comment: It denotes tensor product.

Answer (score 1):

It denotes a tensor product; I would do a no better job of describing it than the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product.

To understand tensor products from a linear algebra/module theory perspective I like Dummit and Foote's exposition. Formally the equality you have above comes from the parametrization $z= x+iy$, $\bar{z} = x -iy$, and billinearity of the tensor product.